# Mocking a DataServiceQuery<TElement>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mocking, wcf-data-services

**How can I mock a DataServiceQuery for unit testing purpose?**

Long Details follow:
Imagine an ASP.NET MVC application, where the controller talks to an ADO.NET DataService that encapsulates the storage of our models (for example sake we'll be reading a list of Customers). With a reference to the service, we get a generated class inheriting from DataServiceContext:

```
namespace Sample.Services
{
  public partial class MyDataContext : global::System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext
  {
    public MyDataContext(global::System.Uri serviceRoot) : base(serviceRoot) { /* ... */ }

    public global::System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery<Customer> Customers
    {
      get
      {
        if((this._Customers==null))
        {
          this._Customers = base.CreateQuery<Customer>("Customers");
        }
        return this._Customers;
      }
    }
    /* and many more members */
  }
}
```

The Controller could be:

```
namespace Sample.Controllers
{
  public class CustomerController : Controller
  {
    private IMyDataContext context;

    public CustomerController(IMyDataContext context)
    {
      this.context=context;
    }

    public ActionResult Index() { return View(context.Customers); }
  }
}
```

As you can see, I used a constructor that accepts an IMyDataContext instance so that we can use a mock in our unit test:

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestCustomerController
{
  [Test]
  public void Test_Index()
  {
    MockContext mockContext = new MockContext();
    CustomerController controller = new CustomerController(mockContext);

    var customersToReturn = new List<Customer>
    {
      new Customer{ Id=1, Name="Fred" },
      new Customer{ Id=2, Name="Wilma" }
    };
    mockContext.CustomersToReturn = customersToReturn;

    var result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;

    var models = result.ViewData.Model;

    //Now we have to compare the Customers in models with those in customersToReturn,
    //Maybe by loopping over them?
    foreach(Customer c in models) //*** LINE A ***
    {
      //TODO: compare with the Customer in the same position from customersToreturn
    }
  }
}
```

MockContext and MyDataContext need to implement the same interface IMyDataContext:

```
namespace Sample.Services
{
  public interface IMyDataContext
  {
    DataServiceQuery<Customer> Customers { get; }
    /* and more */
  }
}
```

However, when we try and implement the MockContext class, we run into problems due to the nature of DataServiceQuery (which, to be clear, we're using in the IMyDataContext interface simply because that's the data type we found in the auto-generated MyDataContext class that we started with). If we try to write:

```
public class MockContext : IMyDataContext
{
  public IList<Customer> CustomersToReturn { set; private get; }

  public DataServiceQuery<Customer> Customers { get { /* ??? */ } }
}
```

In the Customers getter we'd like to instantiate a DataServiceQuery instance, populate it with the Customers in CustomersToReturn, and return it. The problems I run into:

**1~** DataServiceQuery has no public constructor; to instantiate one you should call CreateQuery on a DataServiceContext; see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646677.aspx)

**2~** If I make the MockContext inherit from DataServiceContext as well, and call CreateQuery to get a DataServiceQuery to use, the service and query have to be tied to a valid URI and, when I try to iterate or access the objects in the query, it will try and execute against that URI. In other words, if I change the MockContext as such:

```
namespace Sample.Tests.Controllers.Mocks
{
  public class MockContext : DataServiceContext, IMyDataContext
  {
    public MockContext() :base(new Uri("http://www.contoso.com")) { }

    public IList<Customer> CustomersToReturn { set; private get; }

    public DataServiceQuery<Customer> Customers
    {
      get
      {
        var query = CreateQuery<Customer>("Customers");
        query.Concat(CustomersToReturn.AsEnumerable<Customer>());
        return query;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, in the unit test, we get an error on the line marked as LINE A, because http://www.contoso.com doesn't host our service. The same error is triggered even if LINE A tries to get the number of elements in models.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[Disclaimer - I work at Typemock]*

Have you considered using a mocking framework?

You can use Typemock Isolator to create a fake instance of DataServiceQuery:

```
var fake = Isolate.Fake.Instance<DataServiceQuery>();
```

And you can create a similar fake DataServiceContext and set it's behavior instead of trying to inherit it.

Comment: Dror, thanks for the idea, but for the time being we're not using any mocking framework. We'd be interested in seeing if there is a solution that doesn't rely on one. Still, thank you

Comment: Do you have a specific reason not to use a mocking framework?

Comment: In general, no specific reason. We might introduce it, but it's unlikely we'll do it overnight for this specific task. So, let's say that for now we'd like to find a solution without adding a mocking framework.

Comment: Marking this as the answer since the team decided to use a mocking framework (finally)

Comment: @FOR I'm glad to hear you've made the jump - let me knew if you need any assistance.

Comment: Mocking frameworks that use LinFu or Castle DynamicProxy under the hood still ultimately rely on inheritance to create a proxy object. Since DataServiceQuery's constructor is internal to the MS assembly, and this answer apparently works, does it stand to reason that TypeMock is doing some other magic under the hood that doesn't rely on inheritance?

Comment: You're right - Typemock is using the Profiler API to weaver code during JIT

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by creating an interface `IDataServiceQuery` with two implementations:

- `DataServiceQueryWrapper`
- `MockDataServiceQuery`

I then use `IDataServiceQuery` wherever I would have previously used a `DataServiceQuery`.

```
public interface IDataServiceQuery<TElement> : IQueryable<TElement>, IEnumerable<TElement>, IQueryable, IEnumerable
{
    IDataServiceQuery<TElement> Expand(string path);

    IDataServiceQuery<TElement> IncludeTotalCount();

    IDataServiceQuery<TElement> AddQueryOption(string name, object value);
}
```

The `DataServiceQueryWrapper` takes a `DataServiceQuery` in it's constructor and then delegates all functionality to the query passed in.  Similarly, the `MockDataServiceQuery` takes an `IQueryable` and delegates everything it can to the query.

For the mock `IDataServiceQuery` methods, I currently just return `this`, though you could do something to mock the functionality if you want to.

For example:

```
// (in DataServiceQueryWrapper.cs)
public IDataServiceQuery<TElement> Expand(string path)
{
    return new DataServiceQueryWrapper<TElement>(_query.Expand(path));
}
```

```
// (in MockDataServiceQuery.cs)
public IDataServiceQuery<TElement> Expand(string path)
{
    return this;
}
```